# Problems with TCGAbiolinks

Tags: r

I'm using TCGAbiolinks library on a server. I'm using the following script to do that:

```
qry.rna <- GDCquery(project = "TCGA-BRCA",
            data.category= "Transcriptome Profiling",
            data.type = "Gene Expression Quantification",
            workflow.type = "STAR - Counts")
```

Then, I obtained this as a result:

```
 Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  GDC server down, try to use this package later
```

I'm working on a server and I don't know what happens, please help me

Comment: What is GDC? if whatever organization's this is has their server down, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.